# Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown OnModelCreating in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stack-overflow, code-first

I have received StackOverflowException as when I want to run my project. I got this error several times but after a while it's gone and I didn't received it until now that I can't run my project at all. I don't know exactly why Visual studio 2019 can't run my project and build my context. For notice, I have a large database which I create my code first context by "CodeFirst From Database" operation.

[This is image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdAbJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just break your method into a few sub-methods and run your project.

[image]

[image]

Comment: And how would breaking methods into sub methods help with a StackOverflowException?

Comment: If the number of database tables is large, the number of lines of code generated by the entity framework is large and causes an error, so should be reduced by breaking inside a few sub-methods.